# Demonstrating that $f(x) = x^2 + 1$ is bijective and calculating $f \circ f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I did this exercise. I am not sure if my surjective proof is right - is it good? In fact, I'm not even sure what exactly am I trying to prove (I know that surjective means that each element in the codomain should have a preimage in the domain, but I don't really see how to prove that - I was just mimicking some example I had seen before). Could you give more insight on how to prove a function surjective?

The rest of the exercise is here as well, in case I did a related mistake.

> Let $f:[0,+\infty[ \rightarrow [1,+\infty[$ defined by
>
> $$f(x) = x^2 + 1$$
>
> Demonstrate that it is bijective.

**Injective**

$$f(a) = f(b)$$

$$a^2+1 = b^2 + 1$$

$$a^2 = b^2$$

Since $a,b >= 0$, it is safe to affirm that

$$a = b$$

**Surjective**

$$b = f(a)$$

$$b = a^2 + 1$$

$$b - 1 = a^2$$

$$a = \sqrt{b - 1}$$

---

> Calculate $f^{-1}$ and verify that $f \circ f^{-1}(x) = x$.

$$f^{-1}(x) = \sqrt{x - 1}$$

And

$$f \circ f^{-1}(x)$$

$$f(f^{-1}(x))$$

$$(\sqrt{x - 1})^2+1$$

$$x - 1 + 1$$

$$x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you're exactly correct, for we have

$$f(a) = a^2 + 1 = \Big(\sqrt{b - 1}\Big)^2 + 1 = b - 1 + 1 = b$$

as desired. This is the important thing to prove.

---

The general strategy to show that a function is surjective is two-fold:

- Find a candidate for the preimage by working backwards (i.e. scratchwork)
- Show that the candidate actually works

Now in a case such as this where all the steps in solving for $a$ in terms of $b$ are reversible, these steps are really equivalent.